# C# LINQ - Include Where Condition only if it is not null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have multiple input parameters which I want to check in where clause but I want to check only if the parameter is not null. If it is not null then I don't want that parameter to be in the where clause.

Current Working like this:

```
if(userId != null){
list.Where(x=> x.Id == id && x.UserId == userId);
}
else{
list.where(x=> x.Id == id)
}
```

This is not feasible if we have multiple parameters which can be null or not null as it would create nested if conditions. What could be the best solution here?

Comment: `list.Where(x=> x.Id == id && (userId == null || x.UserId == userId))` or `var query = list.where(x=> x.Id == id)` then `query = userId != null ? query.Where(x.UserId == userId) : query;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
list.Where(x=> x.Id == id && (userId == null || userId == x.UserId));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension;

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereIf<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    bool condition, 
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return condition
        ? source.Where(predicate)
        : source;
}
```

and use it like this;

```cs
list.Where(x=> x.Id == id)
    .WhereIf(userId != null, x=> x.UserId == userId);
```

Taken from https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/ce991482b7e83f369045073986e9c7fdd2b18534/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Core/System/Collections/Generic/AbpEnumerableExtensions.cs#L42

There is also `IQueryable` [version](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Core/System/Linq/AbpQueryableExtensions.cs).

Comment: That was pretty neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, using a inline if statement:

```
list.Where(x =>
   (x.Id == id) &&
   (x.UserId == (userId != null) ? userId : x.UserId)
);
```

I don't know if this is the only solution but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to work with `IEnumerable`, in this case and combine queries:

```cs
var query = list.Where(x=> x.Id == id);

if (userId != null)
{
   query = query.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

The same approach is applicable to `IQueryable`